# Getting error while updating state (skipping the constructor for state)

Tags: reactjs

I am creating simple react program where I have created an array of language and mapping it to create list items and when the user clicks on list item of language it should call updateLanguage method and update state accordingly but I am getting an error. Can anyone help me to resolve an issue.

code ::

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Popular extends React.Component {
   state = {
      selectedLanguage: 'All'
   };

   updateLanguage() {
    this.setState(lang => ({
      selectedLanguage: lang 
    }));
}

   render() {
      const languages = ['All', 'JavaScript', 'Ruby', 'Java', 'CSS', 'Python'];
      console.log();

      return (
        <div>
            <ul className = 'languages'>
            <p> Selected Language: {this.state.selectedLanguage} </p>
              {languages.map((lang) => {
               return (
                  <li 
                    onClick={this.updateLanguage} 
                    key={lang}> 
                    {lang}
                  </li>
               )
              })}
            </ul>
          </div>
      );
   }
}

export default Popular;
```

error ::

[image]

Comment: Try to replace `onClick={this.updateLanguage}` with this `onClick={this.updateLanguage.bind(this}`

Comment: Did but still getting an error

Comment: It seems problem with your updateLanguage() binding and the state declaration. Please check my answer below.

Comment: @Shubham Khatri my question is not similar to what you marked as duplicate. I am skipping the constructor for state. please unmark it

Comment: Skipping the constructor for state is not what the duplicate says, you need to bind the function in which you use setState, in your case you would need to bind updateLanguage, you can either use constructor for it or use arrow functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the following changes:

- Bind the updateLanguage() with **this** (do that in constructor)
- Declare state in constructor

Update yor code as following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Popular extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    selectedLanguage: 'All'
  };
  this.updateLanguage = this.updateLanguage.bind(this);
 }

 updateLanguage(lang) {
  this.setState({ selectedLanguage: lang })
 }

 render() {
  let languages = ['All', 'JavaScript', 'Ruby', 'Java', 'CSS', 'Python'];
 return (
  <div>
    <ul className = 'languages'>
    <p> Selected Language: {this.state.selectedLanguage} </p>
    {languages.map((lang) => {
       return (
          <li 
             onClick={this.updateLanguage}
             key={lang}> 
             {lang}
          </li>
       )
    })}
    </ul>
 </div>
 );


 }
}

export default Popular;
```

Comment: constructor is old way to declare state

Comment: What do you mean "old way"? That's how you're supposed to bind functions and set the initial state (if you're using ES6). If not using ES6 the initial state is defined in `getInitialState()` (as per official React's documentation)